Incompatible pointer types when declaring a struct
list.h: In function ‘CreateNewLinks’:
list.h:29:20: warning: assignment to ‘numbers *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘struct numbers *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   29 |             linked = linked->NextNum;

Code:
typedef struct{
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
}numbers;


numbers *CreateNewLinks(){

    numbers *head=NULL;
    
    head=malloc(sizeof(numbers));
    numbers* linked = head;
    
    char answer;
    
    do{
    
        printf("Enter number : ");
        scanf("%d",&linked->num);
        
        printf("Do you want to add (y/n) : ");
        scanf("%c",&answer);
        
        if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y'){
            linked->NextNum = malloc(sizeof(numbers));
            linked = linked->NextNum;
        }else
           linked->NextNum = NULL;
    
    }while(answer =='y' || answer == 'Y');
    
    return head;
}

How can this problem be solved?

Choosing the correct language tag would be a good first step.

The struct doesn't have a name, so struct numbers doesn't name this struct. And the typedef numbers isn't visible until the next line.

There's a strong argument that using typedef to hide data types is a bad idea.  So you save some keystrokes when you type?  You also lose clear indication of data types.  Given how little time is actually spent typing code compared to how much time is spend looking at it and thinking about it, saving a few keystrokes at the cost of clarity and maintainability is not a good trade.  typedef is a useful tool when it can simplify and clarify code, such as when it's used for function pointers.  IMO using it to save keystrokes and hide information is not a good use.

Also, some newer C programmers seem to form the misunderstanding that typedef is part of the syntax for defining structure types.  It is not.  Typedef declarations can be combined with structure type definitions, but such a combined declaration is still doing two logically distinct things -- defining a structure type and declaring an alias for that type -- and these can just as well be done separately.

You never defined struct numbers, so when it sees it, it assumes it's some distinct type from the numbers type.  You can fix it by adding the missing tag to the typedef:
typedef struct numbers {
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
} numbers;

If you'd rather use numbers inside the structure as well, you can instead do:
typedef struct numbers *numbers;
struct numbers {
    int num;
    numbers *NextNum;
};

This is a fairly common idiom.

First you give the structure a tag:
struct numbers

Then you define the structure using that tag:
struct numbers {
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
};

Then you give the structure type a name:
typedef struct numbers {
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
} numbers;

In your original code, where you have struct numbers *NextNum;, there is no declaration of the tag numbers yet. So the compiler takes struct numbers to refer to some type it does not yet have a definition for.
The code typedef struct{ starts the definition of a structure type with no tag. The code struct numbers will never refer to this structure type, because a structure type with no tag and a structure type with a tag will never be the same type.
The code typedef struct{…}numbers; gives the structure type a name, numbers. But a name is not a tag. The name numbers by itself will refer to the structure type, but it refers to the structure with no tag. It does not refer to the structure type with a tag, struct numbers. numbers and struct numbers are different types. (This is different from C++, where structure, union, and class tags are automatically names of the types.)
In linked = linked->NextNum;, linked->NextNum is a pointer to struct numbers, but linked is a pointer to numbers. Since these are different types, and the assignment between them is inappropriate, the compiler warns you. Changing the structure definition as shown above will resolve this.

typedef struct{
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
}numbers;

Let's break these into two separate operations:
struct {
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
};

// And now the typedef.

Do you see the missing tag? struct numbers was never defined. It should be:
struct numbers {
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
}

And now you can define an alias for struct numbers:
typedef struct numbers numbers;

Or do it like you were originally trying to:
typedef struct numbers {
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
} numbers;


In this typedef declaration
typedef struct{
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
}numbers;

there are declared two different type specifiers. The first one is the unnamed structure of complete type alias of which is numbers. The second one is the incomplete structure type struct numbers. That is there are two type specifiers numbers and struct numbers. They are different types and as a result are incompatible and hence pointers to objects of these types are also incompatible.
You need to introduce a structure tag as for example
typedef struct numbers{
    int num;
    struct numbers *NextNum;
}numbers;

or
typedef struct numbers numbers;
struct numbers{
    int num;
    numbers *NextNum;
};

There is one more problem with your function. The format string in this call of scanf
scanf("%c",&answer);

should have a leading space like
scanf(" %c",&answer);
      ^^^  

It allows to skip white space characters. Otherwise your call of scanf will also read for example the new line character '\n' that is placed in the buffer after pressing the Enter key in the preceding call of scanf
scanf("%d",&linked->num);

Also you need to check whether memory was successfully allocated in calls of malloc.
Pay attention to that the function should do only one task. This do-while loop
do{
    printf("Enter number : ");
    scanf("%d",&linked->num);
    //...
}while(answer =='y' || answer == 'Y');

should be moved from the function in main. That is you need to write a function that appends only one node to the list and will be called from a loop similar to shown above.
